# Best practices how to hide elements in web app using Angular

Tags: angularjs

For example we have a web app and sometimes we need to hide or show some custom directives or html parts using `ng-if/ng-show/ng-hide`. What we do, we click on a link "Example Show Link" and our elements appear or disappear.

So, here is the Problem:

When you go to another `page/state/controller` of course your directive/html part is still visible.

Is there any cool solution to hide this parts? 
Except using `rootScope` or pushing `true/false` flag in every `controller`, 'couse there could be a lot of directives and a lot of controller

Comment: Sanjay Sahani, thanks but I'm not sure that that is really what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use routes for this, and [ui-router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router) is what I think the best one that handles this. When you use routes, only the current states' templates are shown, when you navigate out of the state, its template (together with all the directives in it) are destroyed. It automatically do it for you.

Comment: Yes, I use ui-router but I haven't found the solution in it. Could you please tell me which way should I look for? I'm using flag true/false for this. But when state is changed of course it doesn't change my flag

Comment: I've found a solution using $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart'...)  . This is it? Or you know another solution?

Comment: @DarthJS i edited my answer, I hope it answers your question